Remove headers from being summed in SQL
I am working to sum columns of data by a given category e.g. public spend by country from my file expenditure
SELECT SUM(public spending) AS public spending,
country FROM expenditure
group by country
The above works but it's also pulling through the columnn header with a null for the sum e.g.



Country
public spending




Australia
1012


Belarus
52


Country
null


Denmark
755



Is there anyway for country to only be as a column header and not in the data?
Thanks!
Expected a table with only the countries not the column header also
EDIT:
My public spending data was numeric, switching this to float has helped.
For those asking in the example above the table I expected was:
| Country  | public spending |
| --------  | --------       |
| Australia | 1012           |
| Belarus   | 52             |
| Denmark   | 755            |
Input data for the table above is bwlo, as you can see no country in the rows only column names
| Country  | public spending |
| --------  | --------       |
| Australia | 500            |
| Australia | 512            |
| Denmark   | 500            |
| Denmark   | 255            |
| Belarus   | 12             |
| Belarus   | 18             |
| Belarus   | 22             |

It must be a row in your table. Either clean the table or modify your query where country <> 'Country'

What do you mean by "header"? Please show both sample input data and the expected result.

Its all about having clean data. You can see your sample has "Country" as a row value in a column named Country. Just clean it up and the rest will be easy. Do not try to settle with "where country != 'country'" etc filter, because instead of cleaning up data you will create some tech debt for the future.
